# Using the keyboard print data

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have a problem with python 2.7.
Question: When I use the zoom function, I can not use the "keyboard" to print my real data. Here, I add the keyboard event in my code.
How do I exist in both functions? How should I debug the code?

```
 import matplotlib
    import sys
    import random
    matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    import re
    
    class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
        def __init__(self, parent=None, width=10, height=4, dpi=100):
            FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
            self.setParent(parent)
            FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
            self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(211)
            self.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.on_move)
            self.po_annotation = []
            self.ff=[]
        def start_static_plot(self):
            for i in range(0, 990):
                (point,) = self.axes.plot(x, y, "-o")
                annotation = self.axes.annotate(
                    ("x=" + str(x), "y=" + str(y)),
                    textcoords="data",
                    horizontalalignment="left",
         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple",connectionstyle="arc3,rad=+0.2"),                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="w", edgecolor="0.1", alpha=0.9)
                annotation.set_visible(False)
                self.po_annotation.append([point, annotation])
            self.axes.set_xlim(-0.5, 1000)
            self.axes.set_ylim(-5, 9.5 ** 2)  
        def on_move(self, event):
            visibility_changed = Ture
            for point, annotation in self.po_annotation:
                should_be_visible = point.contains(event)[4]
                if should_be_visible != annotation.get_visible():
                    visibility_changed = True
                    annotation.set_visible(should_be_visible)
                    datachouse=str(annotation)
                    self.ff = np.loadtxt(f)
            if visibility_changed:
                self.draw()                
          def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
                if(event.button() == Qt.LeftButton):    
        def initUi(self):
            self.mpl.start_static_plot()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.mpl)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the default behavior of a method then you must invoke the parent method:

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    super(MyMplCanvas, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        print("result=", self.ff)
```